# Push object into nested Typescript array, get error: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I've been looking around SO for a bit trying to solve this but my code seems to go a little beyond a standard "push object into array."

I have an interface that types a "Year" property with another interface as an array:

```
   export interface IUser {
        Nickname: string;
        FirstName: string;
        LastName: string;
        Email: string;
        EmergencyContact: string;
        EmergencyNumber: string;
        Year: Array<IYear>;
        IsTeacher: boolean;
        IsAdmin: boolean;
        Uid: string;
    }

    export interface IYear {
        CalendarYear: string;
        PassType: string;
        UserItinerary: IItinerary;
        WaiverStatus: boolean;
        Guests: Array<IGuest>;
        SignupDate: string;
    }
```

At a certain point I'm going to pass some formGroup data into the IYear typed property:

```
user: IUser = <IUser>{};

createUser(
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    email: string,
    uid: string,
    isTeacher: boolean,
    passType: string) {
    const year: IYear = {
      CalendarYear: this.calendarYear,
      PassType: passType,
      UserItinerary: {} as IItinerary,
      WaiverStatus: false,
      Guests: [],
      SignupDate: this.dateTime
    }
    this.user.FirstName = firstName;
    this.user.LastName = lastName;
    this.user.Email = email;
    this.user.Uid = uid;
    this.user.IsTeacher = isTeacher;
    this.user.IsAdmin = false;
    this.user.Year.push(year);

    return this.user;
  }
```

The problem is, when I try to pass the 'year' property inside of createUser into the 'this.user.Year' array, I get the error

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

I've tried explicitly passing in the values by key:

```
this.user.Year['CalendarYear'] = year.CalendarYear;
```

But that didn't work. Can anyone point out my mistake here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Year array in the user Object should be initialized to empty before pushing objects into it.

```
this.user.Year = [];
```

and then,

```
this.user.Year.push(year);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get the error is because you have to **first initialize an array**, and then you can `push()` values to it.

- Either initialize a new `IUser` with a `year = [{your year}]`, and **then** you can push more values to it.
- Or initialize a new `IUser` object with an empty array year, and **then** you can push values to it.

Answer (score 1):

you have initialize your array before use it.

```
user: IUser = <IUser>{};    
createUser(
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    email: string,
    uid: string,
    isTeacher: boolean,
    passType: string) {
    const year: IYear = {
      CalendarYear: this.calendarYear,
      PassType: passType,
      UserItinerary: {} as IItinerary,
      WaiverStatus: false,
      Guests: [],
      SignupDate: this.dateTime
    }
    this.user.FirstName = firstName;
    this.user.LastName = lastName;
    this.user.Email = email;
    this.user.Uid = uid;
    this.user.IsTeacher = isTeacher;
    this.user.IsAdmin = false;
    this.user.Year=[];
    this.user.Year.push(year);    
    return this.user;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `Year` is present on the user object and also `CalendarYear` is present on the `Year` object